# What is the difference between regression and state-space models?

Tags: regression, time-series, state-space-models

I would like to know the differences between a regression model with autocorrelated errors and state space models (time series). When should each be used?

According to [this lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lLuPMheNJic), regression (linear or non-linear) with correlated errors takes into account the correlated random effects to model (deterministic) fixed effects, whereas state-space model allows you to actually *model* the autoregressive effect (hidden random walk). However, it is still not very clear to me.